# Who found the proof for the quartic formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, math-history, quartics

A quartic equation is a 4th degree polynomial, in the form of $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$. There are 4 different formulae for the 4 roots of the quartic equation. Here are the formulae:
$$x_1=-\frac{b}{4 a}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}-\frac{2 c}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{2 a^2}-\frac{4 c}{3 a}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}-\frac{-\frac{b^3}{a^3}+\frac{4 c b}{a^2}-\frac{8 d}{a}}{4 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}-\frac{2 c}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}}}}$$

$$x_2=-\frac{b}{4 a}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}-\frac{2 c}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{2 a^2}-\frac{4 c}{3 a}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}-\frac{-\frac{b^3}{a^3}+\frac{4 c b}{a^2}-\frac{8 d}{a}}{4 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}-\frac{2 c}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}}}}$$

$$x_3=-\frac{b}{4 a}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}-\frac{2 c}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{2 a^2}-\frac{4 c}{3 a}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}+\frac{-\frac{b^3}{a^3}+\frac{4 c b}{a^2}-\frac{8 d}{a}}{4 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}-\frac{2 c}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}}}}$$

$$x_4=-\frac{b}{4 a}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}-\frac{2 c}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{2 a^2}-\frac{4 c}{3 a}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}+\frac{-\frac{b^3}{a^3}+\frac{4 c b}{a^2}-\frac{8 d}{a}}{4 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} a}+\frac{b^2}{4 a^2}-\frac{2 c}{3 a}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)}{3 a \sqrt[3]{2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e+\sqrt{\left(2 c^3-9 b d c-72 a e c+27 a d^2+27 b^2 e\right)^2-4 \left(c^2-3 b d+12 a e\right)^3}}}}}}$$ 
Yep, they are really long, I apologize for the loading time. I want to know who spent so much time finding these formulae and how they found them.

Comment: In [this video](https://youtu.be/N-KXStupwsc), Mathologer shows how one solves the cubic equation. Then at the very end how you use that to solve the quartic in just a few minutes. Have a look. Spoiler: No one found _that_ formula. They simplified the problem, solved the simplified problem, then transformed back. Note how many terms and expressions in your formulas are basically the same, only with a sign change here and there. That's the result of _loads_ of simplifying substitutions.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation

Comment: Hopefully this will be migrated to hsm.se.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago (in the context of "Jugend forscht"), I retraced the development of these really old formulas (from degree 3 up to some special cases of degree 5) that have their origin in the 16th century. On page 15 in the document ["Jugend Forscht" (PDF)](https://sultanow.info/misc/mathematics/Jugend%20Forscht/Jugend%20Forscht%20(Gleichungen%203.%20bis%205.%20Grades).pdf) you find the case of degree 4.

As I remember, [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) developed a method for calculating the four roots of an quartic equation. The following links might be helpful:

- [Descartes’ Method for Constructing Roots of Polynomials with ‘Simple’ Curves - 'Depressed' Quartics and Cubics](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/descartes-method-for-constructing-roots-of-polynomials-with-simple-curves-depressed-quartics-and)
- [Descartes method (fourth degree equation)](https://second.wiki/wiki/mc3a9todo_de_descartes_ecuacic3b3n_de_cuarto_grado)

Ron Irving's book ["Beyond the Quadratic Formula"](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/ebooks/pdf/BQF_preface.pdf) gives a nice chapter on Descartes’ method (page 149) and on Ferrari's method (page 146), who was apparently the first discoverer of these formulas.

***Edit:***

As correctly pointed out by the comment of WhatsUp, Ferrari discovered first, how to find the roots of a quartic equation. Cardano published it originally in his book ["Ars Magna" (PDF in Latin language)](http://www.filosofia.unimi.it/cardano/testi/operaomnia/vol_4_s_4.pdf). A nice essay explaining it in English can be found in the chapter ["Cardano’s Ars Magna" (PDF)](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Esohum/ma330/files/eqns_2.pdf).

Comment: In [this wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#History), it is said that the solution is found by Lodovico Ferrari in 1540 and published by Gerolamo Cardano in 1545.

Comment: Ok - that is very intersting. I knew that Ferrari (and later Cardano) discovered the formula for solving cubic equations (called [Cardano Formula](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Cardano_formula)). I will check this carefully and fix my answer.